# Javascript confirm delete and edit in same form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have two submit buttons on the same form for edit and delete and I want to make delete confirmation alert. I've tried but this only work yes however I select "no/cancel" in delete confirmation. What should I do ?

This is the form

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="update.php">
//form code
<input name="update_button" type="submit" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_button" onClick="javascript:confirmDelete();" value="Delete"/>
```

This is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete()
{
    var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
    if(status)
    {
        parent.location.replace("parent.location='<?php echo "update.php";?>'");
    }else
    {
        parent.location.replace("parent.location='<?php echo "form.php?ticket=".$c['no'] ?>'");
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the update.php

```
if(isset($_POST['update_button']))
{
    //update proses
}
else if(isset($_POST['delete_button']))
{
    //delete proses
}
```

I want delete confirmation show "Are you sure you want to delete ?" if I select "yes", it would delete from database and if I choose "Cancel", it will stay at current page (form.php).

Thanks before,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `javascript:` in `onclick` or any event handling attribute. Just use `onclick="return confirmDelete();"`

and your javascript will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmDelete() {
    var status  = confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete ?" );
    return status;
  }
</script>
```

alternately you can use `onclick="return confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete ?' );"`

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="">
<input name="update_button" type="submit" value="Update" />
<input type="button" name="delete_button" id="delete_button" value="Delete"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#delete_button").on('click',function(){
  if(confirmDelete()){
    parent.location.replace("parent.location='<?php echo "update.php";?>'");
  }
  else{
      parent.location.replace("parent.location='<?php echo "form.php?ticket=".$c['no'] ?>'");
   }
});

function confirmDelete(){
  var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
    if(status)
    {
        return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```